# ConEmu - Startup on top

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, console, conemu

I integrated ConEmu to the context menu. So far it works. However, the new console starts up behind the opened explorer window instead of on top (like cmd).

Here is the full command from registry:

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" -here -run {cmd} -new_console
```

I'm using Windows 10

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81UZw.gif)

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: Show screenshots

Comment: @Maximus I edited my question